# Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried getting GetHttpResponse which is the below code. I have tried to project resync to no avail.

> Full error : Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory
>   'libs'] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

```
   configure(':app') {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
            compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
            compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
```

This is my gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "itp361.nyp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

This is my gradle app file .
I have searched many different questions and applied it but it still prompts me the error. I have also added executable jar 'org.arpache.http.leagcy' to C:\Users\user\Downloads\NYP\NYP\app\libs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the note.

```
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
```

You are in the project `build.gradle`. You have to put your dependencies into the module `build.gradle`. It's the second snippet you posted.

Comment: After changing it works for me but i still cannot "resolve symbol httpresponse '. What is wrong?

Comment: @HahaHehe That's another question, but you have to import the package. In Android Studio you can press ALT + ENTER to get auto suggestions to solve the issue. Please don't ask multiple questions in one thread next time.

Comment: can i ask this question and link you instead ? so sorry and noted

Comment: Sorry but how do I import the package . I have only picked up android studio a few weeks ago and is still learning the ropes . I have to wait another 90 mins to post another question but if you could help me out and you post your answer later, I will upvote and put as answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said. Put your cursor on the dotted red line (where the error is) and press `ALT + ENTER`. Choose `import xyz`.

Comment: Im  so sorry its my bad as I have not created the class .